# Strict standards: Non-static method Cache::get() should not be called statically in Concrete5

Tags: php, concrete5

In concrete5, when I move the site, I got `"Strict standards: Non-static method Cache::get() should not be called statically"` , I have tried the suggested solutions in concrete5 (http://www.concrete5.org/community/forums/installation/concrete5-broke-after-updating-php-apache-to-include-a-few-addit/) But sill the error is showing.

If there is solution other than downgrading php, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change the error reporting to disable `E_STRICT` in php5.4+.

The commits that fixed this are https://github.com/concrete5/concrete5/commit/a0fa442ccbfa78b28f1f5cedb517a58b762ca019
and
https://github.com/concrete5/concrete5/commit/86735143059746e8db5ff71e9fe5a8570796f3c5

See [concrete5 documentation](http://legacy-documentation.concrete5.org/tutorials/how-fix-strict-standards-error) for recommended ways to fix this.